# custom hook -> useEffect -> while loop not breaking

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I try to create a custom hook for polling.

## Problem:

My hook is using a while loop inside useEffect, but it seems that while loop is never breaking, even when I change the condition to false.

## Code sandbox reproducing the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-worker-jm1p5?file=/src/App.tsx

## Code:

I have 2 files:

1. usePolling.ts (which is my hook)
2. App.tsx (where I am executing/calling the hook)

###### usePolling.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

export interface PollingOptions<T> {
  fetchFunc: () => Promise<T> | undefined;
}

export const usePolling = <T>(
  { fetchFunc }: PollingOptions<T>,
  interval: number
) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState(true);

  const stopPolling = useCallback(() => {
    setCondition(false);
  }, []);

  const performPolling = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetchFunc();
      setData(res);
    } catch (err) {
        setCondition(false);
        setError(err);
        return;
    } finally {
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, interval));
    }
  }, [fetchFunc, interval]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      while (condition) {
        await performPolling();
      }
    })();

    return () => stopPolling();
  }, [condition, performPolling, stopPolling, data]);

  return { data, error, stopPolling };
};
```

###### App.tsx

```
import { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { usePolling } from "./usePolling";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const fetchFunc = useCallback(async () => {
    // please consider this as an API call
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
    return { isSigned: Math.random() < 0.5 };
  }, []);

  const { data, error, stopPolling } = usePolling({ fetchFunc }, 3000);

  console.log(data, error, ">>>>>>>");

  const isSigned = data?.isSigned;

  const isContractSigned = useMemo(() => {
    if (isSigned) stopPolling();
    return isSigned || false;
  }, [isSigned, stopPolling]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{`Is contract signed: ${isContractSigned}`}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Why am I not using setInterval instead of while loop

If I use setInterval, and if I choose to change the polling interval to 100ms for example. There are 3 problems:

1. there is a very high chance of calling API before previous API call responds.
2. suppose for any reason 2nd API call responded before the first one, then I am in trouble
3. Unnecessary API calls.

If I use while loop instead of setInterval, then all the above mentioned problems are solved. Please note that I am still using setTimeout inside while loop, so it will wait for specified interval before the next iteration.

## Expected solution:

Any solution that does not use setInterval is expected. If you suggest any improvements to the existing code (even not related to this specific problem), you are most welcome :)

Thank you!

Comment: the code inside `useEffect` is going to be run every time your dependencies change. So when `condition` changes, the code inside `useEffect` will be run again, and if `false` the while loop won't execute, however the while loop from the first time `useEffect` was run will still be executing infinitely

Answer (score 1):

The callback you pass as the first argument of useEffect assumes that the dependencies are constants.

You are starting a while loop with the condition being a constant. There is no way to stop that while loop execution.
If you change the condition, it's not going to stop the previous while loop, but start a new condition with the new value.

If the new value is false, it won't start so nothing would happen. But if it's true, then you've got 2 while loops running.

Check out the [SWR, React Hooks for Data Fetching](https://swr.vercel.app/), it's probably exactly what you are looking for.

#### Update:

##### The reason why the while loop won't stop

When you have a while loop in normal code, you control it using a condition based on a **variable**.
The dependencies of a `useEffect` are passed as **constants** to the callback. **So any loops running based on a state variable (truthy) in a useEffect will not terminate.**

The can cleanup a setInterval because there is `clearInterval` function implemented in the browser, which takes an id, finds the reference of the interval, and stops it.
There is no `clearWhileLoop` as it's not feasible.
Whenever a dependency mutates, the cleanup function runs, but you can't do anything about a while loop in a cleanup function.
The next callback is fired with **new constants**.

Check out the docs for [why useEffects run after each render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.

I am not looking to include new dependencies like swr to the project. I have already used swr as well as react-query in past, but I don't want to include it in this project.

If you see my implementation, I return stopPolling in the useEffect. That means, if effect is called another time, it will make sure to break the running while loop before starting a new one. I am not sure why its not the case here.

Can you please try to check my code and can you please suggest me changes in the current implementation itself (if possible)

Thank you!

Comment: No probs Vishal, the gist here is, state variables are to be considered constants when you are dealing with them in a useEffect. Any loops running on a truthy condition based on state variables (truthy) in a useEffect will not terminate. I've updated my answer too.

Comment: Here is the updated hook that still uses while loop and it works perfectly fine now: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-worker-jm1p5?file=/src/usePolling.ts

Comment: Nice vishal! You switched to refs, GG!